# pecl install pecl_http gives no releases available

Tags: php, httprequest, pecl

I'm trying to install the pecl HTTPRequest extension. But when I run the following command on my CentOS server, I get the message that no releases are available and the install has failed.

```
$pecl install pecl_http
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/pecl_http"
install failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit: Pecl config**

```
    Configuration (channel pecl.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    <not set>
Default Channel                default_channel  pecl.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pecl.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /usr/local/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /usr/local/lib/php/doc
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          ./
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /usr/local/lib/php
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /usr/local/lib/php/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /usr/local/lib/php/data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /tmp/pear/download
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /usr/local/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          <not set>
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /tmp/pear/temp
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /usr/local/lib/php/test
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /usr/local/lib/php/htdocs
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            22
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /usr/local/etc/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /home/onsboek/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /usr/local/etc/pear.conf
```

Comment: Show your `pecl config-show` output. Might need to adapt the `preferred_state` thingy or something.

Comment: Can't see anything odd with that. But why don't you use a distribution-supplied php install? (As last resort you could download it yourself, and use `pecl package ./` or so for building it manually.)

Comment: What is your php version ? I had the same warning on php 5.4

Answer (score 1):

Try the following;

```
yum install php-pear
yum install gcc
yum install curl-devel
/usr/bin/pecl install pecl_http
```

Add the following line to /etc/php.ini file: 
    extension=http.so

Restart your apache server so the extension can be loaded:

```
httpd -k restart
```

If it doesn't work, let me know the output.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was a problem:
pecl.php.net did not answer when header "Accept-Encoding:" was total empty.

Adding one single space to that line in pear source-code, solved a problem.

file:  /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/REST.php

line ~405

```
$request .= "AcceptEncoding:\r\n";            //<---original line
$request .= "AcceptEncoding: \r\n";           //<--changed to this (added space)
```

...or simple script can perform the change:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
target=`pecl config-get php_dir`/PEAR/REST.php
        [ -f "$target" ] || { echo file $target not found; exit; }
sed -i 's/Accept-Encoding:\\r\\n/AcceptEncoding: \\r\\n/g' $target
```

Comment: This solved my problem, though I could not understand the reason since I have another server working fine without adding space to Accept-Encoding.

Comment: strange that you are first confirming this, i had this bug in my all 3 different server configurations...